# Why doesn't the logo image appear for the first load of the whole page?

Tags: html, css

I have been testing my website with many devices and found out that the logo image disappeared when I loaded the whole page for the fist time. This happened only on Mac and iPhone. However, when I reloaded the page, the logo image appeared. It seems strange that I have to reload the page to see the logo.

```css
#logo{
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:575px) {
    .navbar-brand{
        text-align: center;
    }
    #logo{
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    } 
}
```

```html
<h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="./images/Logo.PNG" alt=""/></a></h1>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Please help me figure out this problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: I would start by removing the h1 tags that surround your link and image. Then what is the idea behind the attribute position relative in the media query for the logo if there is no other attribute of position absolute any where?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works well now :)

Answer (score 0):

You've put the img inside the h1 tag, which might cause problems.

If that doesn't fix it, I recommend showing the rest of the HTML & CSS of the page - the issue might lie elsewhere.

You could also check for compatibility of your CSS on https://caniuse.com/

Comment: @LoveToLearn my pleasure, good luck with your project.